# How can I get these two slices of an image to align using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days so any help is appreciated.

I used a grid demo to put blocks of text over a background image. The image on top needs to align with the image in the footer but it currently does not align.

The full markup can be seen within this codepen but here is the pertinent part to show the problem http://codepen.io/jbchurchill/pen/NGrRJg

```
<div class="image">
<div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-3">Welcome to the
<h4>Austin - The depths of hell</h4>
</div>
</div>
<!-- row --><div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-3">Lorem Ipsum Dominus fobiscum add some spirit 220. Won't you eat my sleazy pancackes just like saintly Alphonso. The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog. <!-- Ocean on the east and bisected by the Chesapeake Bay, one of the world’s great estuaries. -->  </div>
<div class="incolumn column-3 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="incolumn column-6">As a result Hell  boasts a hot steamy sauna of lava longer than the state of California. We also have some rare historical areas, such as and purgatory and limbo, that provide hours of laughter for the dark angel Satan. We can often be found lounging with our friends by the lava pool drinking Ale and Mead. We find that those are the best drinks for driving away demons. To demonstrate the bankrupt richness that can be found in urban cities, we point you to Austin Texas. Our diversity offers some of the best camaraderie on the sister planett!!</div>
</div>
<!-- row --><div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-5 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="incolumn column-7">To use this dungeon guide, start by selecting a scullion and explore the various clusters of mining sites. <span style="color: yellow">Changing The length of this content affects the size of the gap! Try it yourself and see. It is totally weird (like Austin). I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not I kid you not</span></div>
</div>
<!-- row --><!--
<div class="row"><div class="incolumn column-12 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<p>-->
<!-- row --><div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-12 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- row --><div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-12 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- row --><div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-12 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- row --><div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-12 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- row --><div class="row">
<div class="incolumn column-12 invisible">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

This is output html and css from Drupal 7 which explains some of the extraneous markup. It is also why the footer is not easily made into part of the "image" div.

Next here is the relevant CSS

```
    /*------------------------------*\
    Grid System
\*------------------------------*/

.row, 
.incolumn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
}

.incolumn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.incolumn + .incolumn {
    margin-left: 1.6%;
}

.column-1 {
    width: 6.86666666667%;
}

.column-2 {
    width: 15.3333333333%;
}

.column-3 {
    width: 23.8%;
}

.column-4 {
    width: 32.2666666667%;
}

.column-5 {
    width: 40.7333333333%;
}

.column-6 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

.column-7 {
    width: 57.6666666667%;
}

.column-8 {
    width: 66.1333333333%;
}

.column-9 {
    width: 74.6%;
}

.column-10 {
    width: 83.0666666667%;
}

.column-11 {
    width: 91.5333333333%;
}

.column-12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .column-1, 
    .column-2, 
    .column-3, 
    .column-4, 
    .column-5, 
    .column-6, 
    .column-7, 
    .column-8, 
    .column-9, 
    .column-10, 
    .column-11, 
    .column-12 {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    .incolumn + .incolumn {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

/*------------------------------*\
  IMAGE STYLES
\*------------------------------*/
.incolumn {
    background: #1471E3;
    border: none; 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #222;
    padding-top: 5px;
    min-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* fixes small odd-colored area on the left side of the front page */
div#main.clearfix {
   background: #1471E3;
}
/*
div.field-items {
  max-height: 540px;
}
*/
.invisible {
  /* background-color: blue; */
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
}  

.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.incolumn .column {
    color: #eee;
    background: background-color: #1471E3;
    border: none;
    /* border-color: #000; */
}
/************
Image Class w/ Osprey background
and footer
************/
.node {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('../images/Guide_09.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #1471E3;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 540px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-origin: bottom left;
}
#front-footer {
  max-height: 35px;
  min-height: 35px; /* prevents footer image from disappearing! */
  max-width: 900px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/Guide_10.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div.content, 
.node.node-page,
 {
  padding: 0 important!;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}
div.region.region-content {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .row {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .incolumn {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row:last-child .incolumn:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
} /* end media query */

@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
  .image, #front-footer {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #1471E3;
  }
} /* end media query */
```

Comment: why don't you just use a background image?

Comment: Thanks - both are background images (I edited the question to say so). They are separate images primarily bc I'm not sure I can get the background to cover all that content.